# GTA5 Player Setback

Tags: xbox-360, grand-theft-auto-v

I need some help in resolving this issue.  I have GTA5 for the Xbox.  I've been playing for the past week or so and the story mode is around 15 percent done.  (I've unlocked the 3 guys: Michael, Franklin, and Trevor)

I turned on my Xbox this morning and started playing gta5.  I realized that I was setback to around 4.2 percent done with missions and all I had was Franklin.  I couldn't even access any other people because I would have to redo all of the missions.

I've tried turning off my Xbox, changing accounts, etc.  Nothing seems to work.

Anyone have the same problem?
Any feedback would be much appreciated.  Thanks.

Comment: I was just launching GTA 5, noticed an update 1.01, googled for it to see what's changed, this is one of the results: [Finished the game, installed 1.01, can't switch characters anymore ...](http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/634490-grand-theft-auto-v/67372040). Apparently, reloading a save should fix it. I can't confirm it since I'm still not done downloading the patch...

Comment: Hi Nolonar,  Thanks for the link and suggestion, but when I try to reload a save it just gives me options to recent saves at 4.2 percent.  For some reason its like I lost all of the data after 4.2 percent of the story mode was done, except I still have achievements on my Xbox profile.  On another note, this happened before I updated to the latest update.  I then updated GTA5 thinking the problem would be fixed, but its still prevalent.

Comment: Have you checked for saves on other devices (hdd, usb, cloud)? GTAV initially loads what it thinks is your latest save but then before saving again asks where to save. It's quite easy to load from one device then accidentally start saving to another. From memory pressing "X" on the load screen allows you to change device.

Comment: I don't have the cloud enabled and I've never used a USB device.  I have a fairly large hdd that the Xbox came with so I've always just used that.  I looked under GTA5 in the hdd, and It says that the last save was 4.2 percent.  Hmm...Is there a way that files get deleted from the hdd? Thanks for the reply Peter.

Comment: @MotoCody145 Hey, It looks like you're new, so I just giving you a bit of information. If you are replying to a post use @ & someonesnamewithoutspaces without the & (similar to the beginning of this comment) and they will receive a notification that you mentioned them.

Comment: @MotoCody145 Did you happen to look at the other GTA5 question for xbox that had technical issues? He has yet to accept an answer but it follows a similar pattern in that he lost a lot of data. Only difference is that he lost all progress maybe give it a once over, if you've found a method to fix it.

Answer (score 2):

This happened to me once. If you press start while playing the game and tab across to the game option you can load from a previous save. In my case I had created a save and somehow my xbox date was incorrect meaning the game loaded from the latest save which actually had less percent completion.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes if you don't personally save the game before turning it off it takes you back to the last known saved memory in the game is happened to me a million times even after auto saving